# how to connect View class with xml in eclipse android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

i have my gamefield.xml and i only want is to draw in canvas with onDraw() a rectangle  in gamefield.xml t manipulate... i have been search for the answer but nothing works...

what can i do for this,. Thank you .

This is my gamefield.xmlbu i dont think it is useful.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<View class= "cruz.jayson.bantumi.Board"
    android:id="@+id/myBoard"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: define `doesn't work`.. http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Creating a Custom View Class documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html), your XML should look like this:

```
<cruz.jayson.bantumi.Board
    android:id="@+id/myBoard"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

You specify your View class in the element's name, not in a `class` attribute.